# Calling method on deallocated view controller after popping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, exc-bad-access

I have a uinavigation controller for the menu in my app. It can go three levels deep of menus.

The problem is when I push the second level menu on, scroll all the way to the bottom of its contents (about 200 rows) and pop the view controller once the animation stops in returning to the first level menu it crashes with exc_bad_accs. It doesn't crash if I don't scroll down at least to near the bottom.

Using instruments I see it's referencing the second level menu object that is now deallocated but I can't seem to understand why or where to start looking.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you send some code? We can't know what is the problem if you don't show us some code, because an EXC_BAD_ACCESS means that message was sent to a point in the memory where there’s no instance of a class to execute it. Your title say that you are trying to call a method in a deallocated view controller. So... If you want to call a method of the VC controller you must retain the VC.

Comment: By the title I mean that that is why it's crashing, as per instruments telling me that, not something I was explicitly trying to do. What code should I include knowing that?

Comment: Maybe you can add the code of how do you load the rows. (The whole first and second view controller would be better). And the code where you are popping the view controller.

Comment: set property for your scrollview and viewcontroller

Comment: Are you loading any images asynchronously for the rows of the deallocated tableView? I used to have an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I tapped back while table view was scrolling.